# I want to find out the number between 3 and 4 Identifier like # or @ in given String

Tags: mysql, sql, ssis-2012

I Have a Unique key column like

```
ABCDRF#72665523975#1769#00177#001#2779#NA#Pyddfdfdfd#CAOHGHGHG
```

in which  we have composite few columns and we separated by #.
From this composite key I want to find out the number between `3` and `4` separate

I have used substring with charindex-string-functions-in-sql-queries,
but not able to find out  the expected results.

I want to find out `00177` from above

Comment: Is this for `sql-server` (because of the tag `ssis-2012`), or for `mysql` ????

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the position, you can do it using MySQL [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function:

```
SET @str = 'ABCDRF#72665523975#1769#00177#001#2779#NA#Pyddfdfdfd#CAOHGHGHG';
SET @pos = 4

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str, '#', @pos), 
    '#', -1
);
```

Comment: The column name is COL1 then how can we use this function please explain a little more

Comment: Let's say you have table 'T' and column 'COL1', you can use the code I've written and replace @str with COL1, add a FROM clause with your table name T. You can follow this fiddle: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3xybqmzxj

Comment: how can we do it in SQL

Comment: My code is in SQL. If you can share DDL of your full tables, I'll update my answer accordingly. @PuneetKumar